# How to embed iframe into Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'd like to embed an iframe into a google document. Specifically, within the document itself and not a sidebar or dialog/modal.

Basically, I'd like allow users to do the following

- Paste link
- The position in the document that the link was pasted now renders an embedded iframe of the link

I've read through Google App Sheets documentation. It touches on custom dialogs and some UI, but doesn't really touch on the behavior I'm after.

1 – Can I use the "paste" as a trigger to fire my code? Or do I need a custom menu item to insert the embeddable?
2 – How to embed the iframe into the document itself

Thanks for any help!

Comment: (2) not possible AFAIK.

Comment: What specifically is not possible? The paste trigger, embedding within the document, all?

Comment: (2),i.e, iframe within Google document main interface is not possible. In Sidebar  it maybe possible. Sidebar is pure js.. you can probably listen to ctrl+v or any other trigger, but there maybe( probably is)  restrictions on reading clipboard.

Comment: As @TheMaster mentioned, this is not possible at the moment with the existing features of Google Docs. You can request this feature using the [Google Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/support#developer_product_feedback). AFAIK, you can only embed iFrames to a Google Site.

Comment: iframe is an html tag